# f# sum list in other way

Tags: list, f#

Hello i resolved  problem with ealier task.
Now  if i have for example list = [ 2;  3;  2 ; 6 ] want to translate it like this  [2;5;7;13].

I declared x as my first element and xs as my rest and used List.scan . Idea below

```
  (fun x n -> x + n) 0     
but this make something like this    
   val it : int list = [0; 2; 5; 7; 13]
```

How to rewrite it to make list looking like this [2;5;7;13] with using any starting parameter. When i delete 0 i get error message.

Another question how it's going to look like List.Fold i tried to write something similar but it can get only sum of this list ;( .

Comment: Just take the tail of the output list: `list |> List.scan (+) 0 |> List.tail`

Comment: Thank you ;) I needed that one :) Any hints how to do the same with fold ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do this with a fold (with type annotations):

```ml
let orig = [2; 3; 2; 6]  

let workingSum (origList:int list) : int list =
    let foldFunc (listSoFar: int list) (item:int) : int list =
        let nextValue = 
            match listSoFar with
            | [] -> item
            | head::_ -> head + item
        nextValue::listSoFar

    origList |> List.fold foldFunc [] |> List.rev
```

For help learning fold, here's how I would do this with a recursive function:

```ml
let workingSum' (origList: int list): int list =
    let rec loop (listSoFar: int list) (origListRemaining:int list): int list =
        match origListRemaining with
        | [] -> listSoFar
        | remainHead::remainTail ->
            let nextValue = 
                match listSoFar with
                | [] -> remainHead
                | head::_ -> head + remainHead
            loop (nextValue::listSoFar) remainTail

    origList |> loop [] |> List.rev
```

Note that the signature of the inner `loop` function is really similar to the `foldFunc` of the previous example, with one major difference: instead of being passed in the next element, it's being passed in the remainder of the original list that hasn't been processed yet. I'm using a match expression to account for the two different possibilities of that remainder of the original list: either the list is empty (meaning we're done), or it's not (and we need to return a recursive call to the next step).

Comment: can you explain how  it is working ? And why i must rev list later? I want to learn something :P

Comment: Sure. The state that the fold is building is itself a list. As the fold runs, foldFunc is executed on each element in turn. The fold function has two steps: first, determine the value that needs to be added to the state list; second cons that element with the passed in state list to product the new state. It's actually similar to tail recursive calls.

Comment: I've added a recursive function doing the same thing. Are you able to follow it?

Comment: Ultimately, a list is a stack, right? So while processing one stack into another, you get the items in the stack in reverse order, so that's my there's a `List.rev` call at the end in either approach.

Comment: i will try to follow :D